# Using rate.NewLimiter rate limiter with channels

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, routines

I'm using a rate limiter to throttle the number of requests that are routed

The requests are sent to a channel, and I want to limit the number that are processed per second but i'm struggling to understand if i'm setting this correctly, I don't get an error, but **i'm unsure if i'm even using the rate limiter**

This is what is being added to the channel:

```
type processItem struct {
    itemString string
}
```

Here's the channel and limiter:

```
itemChannel := make(chan processItem, 5)
itemThrottler := rate.NewLimiter(4, 1) //4 a second, no more per second (1)
var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup
```

Items are added to the channel:

```
case "newItem":
    waitGroup.Add(1)
    itemToExec := new(processItem)
    itemToExec.itemString = "item string"
    itemChannel <- *itemToExec
```

Then a go routine is used to process everything that is added to the channel:

```
go func() {
    defer waitGroup.Done()
    err := itemThrottler.Wait(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error with limiter: %s", err)
        return
    }
    for item := range itemChannel {
        execItem(item.itemString) // the processing function
    }
    defer func() { <-itemChannel }()
}()
waitGroup.Wait()
```

Can someone confirm that the following occurs:

- The execItem function is run on each member of the channel 4 times a second

I don't understand what "err := itemThrottler.Wait(context.Background())" is doing in the code, how is this being invoked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... i'm unsure if i'm even using the rate limiter

Yes, you are using the rate-limiter. You are rate-limiting the `case "newItem":` branch of your code.

> I don't understand what "err := itemThrottler.Wait(context.Background())" is doing in the code

`itemThrottler.Wait(..)` will just stagger requests (4/s i.e. every 0.25s) - it does not *refuse* requests if the rate is exceeded. So what does this mean? If you receive a glut of 1000 requests in 1 second:

- 4 requests will be handled immediately; but
- 996 requests will create a backlog of 996 go-routines that will block

The 996 will unblock at a rate of 4/s and thus the backlog of pending go-routines will not clear for another 4 minutes (or maybe longer if more requests come in). A backlog of go-routines may or may not be what you want. If not, you may want to use [Limiter.Allow](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/time/rate#Limiter.Allow) - and if `false` is returned, then refuse the request (i.e. don't create a go-routine) and return a [429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429#:%7E:text=The%20HTTP%20429%20Too%20Many,before%20making%20a%20new%20request.) error (if this is a HTTP request).

Finally, if this is a HTTP request, you should use it's imbedded context when calling `Wait` e.g.

```
func (a *app) myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // ...

    err := a.ratelimiter(r.Context())

    if err != nil {
        // client http request most likely canceled (i.e. caller disconnected)
    }
}
```

Comment: To add some context, I want to not spam our mongod (mongo server) instance with item. Items are basically queries to execute. Our frontend has a dashboard with say 10 charts on it, that's 10 queries sent. Setting the rate limiter to 5,1 would mean execute 5 now, then 5 per second? So it should take ~2 seconds?

Comment: The second parameter of the limiter is "if limiter does it's process of the items in the channel faster than the rate, how many can it do?", is that right?

Comment: 1Q. Yes. 2Q. The second parameter of `NewLimiter` you mean? The 2nd parameter is the burst limit. To use the example above, this could be 1000 - i.e. we are allowing 1000 goroutines to run concurrently, but will limit anything beyond that (i.e. handle this one off burst of requests, but typically requests should be much less frequent).

Comment: @colm.anseo curious.. What's the purpose of passing imbedded context when calling Wait?

Comment: @thiago if the client making the REST call disconnects or the client cancels the request, the server side can detect this early using `r.Context()`. This allows the handler to free up resources (including rate limit settings in this case) and exit early - since it's pointless returning any response to a client that is no longer listening.

Comment: @colm.anseo does it also imply that, for each HTTP request, a new rate limit instance is created with this settings: rate.NewLimiter(4, 1) ?